# selecting blocks on mouse click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 2.5d type game, with falling blocks (like tetris) and orthographic projection setup (I've setup my game as "3D" type).

I've defined a block like this:

```
public class Block{
    public Block () {
        this.gameObj = GameObject.CreatePrimitive (PrimitiveType.Cube);
    }
        public GameObject gameObj;
}
```

I have a BoardMgr (GameObj + script only component), where I spawn these blocks and store them in an array:

```
public class BoardMgr : MonoBehaviour {
    protected Block[] blocks;
    protected Block[,] board;
}
```

In `BoardMgr::update()`, blocks are falling down one after the other (like tetris). Now, I'd like to figure out when I click on a block, which block object is it. This is the click detection code:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
                Debug.Log ("Ray hit block");
                // How do I find which block got hit here ?
            } else {
                Debug.Log ("Ray missed block");
            }
        }
```

When I click on a block, I do see the `ray hit block` on console, but then, how do I access which "Block" object got hit ? From RayCastHit, hit object, how do I decode which Block does it reference ?

I'm new to unity (2 days old) but not new to gamedev. Trying to find my way through unity here. I'd appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction here.

Comment: `hit.collider.gameObject()`? http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html

Comment: @Cyclone But that will yield me a gameObject. In my case that is encapsulated within the `Block` type. I want to get a hold of the Block type reference, since I need to extract other information from that Block type object.

Comment: Can't you solve this by declaring your `Block` like `class Block : GameObject` instead?

Comment: I can. However, how will I get a reference to the block object ? Static cast ?

Comment: Yes I think you should be able to do `Block block = (Block)hit.collider.gameObject();`

Comment: Guess what: GameObject is a sealed type and I cannot do: `class Block : GameObject`. so static cast won't also work..

Comment: What is the structure of the actual gameObject that the falling block is. What scripts does it have attached to it? You can use hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<T>() to get any MonoBehaviour that has a instance on that particular object. But since your Block class is not a Mono you  cant even have a instance of it on a gameObject.

Comment: @UriPopov I'm open to changing my `class Block`. However, I don't see how will making it derive from Mono be helpful ? I'm new to unity, so maybe I'm missing something here.

Comment: @brainydexter if its derived from Mono you can use  hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Block>() to get the instance of the Block component running on the gameObjcet the ray hit. Then you would have to have some sort of ID or name member in the Block class that you use to identify the instance.

Comment: so in a way, I will have to mantain some sort of mapping between Block objects and an id of some sorts, and use that lookup to resolve the correct block object ?

Comment: @brainydexter yep pretty much. You can add a id to the block class and when you instantiate a gameobject assign that id to a component of the game object that you can get from the rayhit.

Comment: for hell's sake guys.   ***YOU CAN SIMPLY USE ONMOUSEDOWN ACTUALLY ON THAT OBJECT***  make a script with onmousedown, and put it ON all those objects.  see what happens

Comment: I thought about onmousedown, however I have a use case where user may select multiple blocks. When the user does so,  I'd like to know what all other blocks have been selected too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//Check the GameObject by name

```
if (hit.collider.name == "brainydexter")
{
Debug.Log("Hit: "+hit.collider.name);
}
```

//Check the GameObject by tag

```
if (hit.collider.CompareTag("brainydexterTag"))
{

}
```

//Check the GameObject by GameObject instance

```
GameObject otherGameObject = gameObject;
if (hit.collider.gameObject == otherGameObject)
{

}
```

EDIT: This is what you need

Use **array** to loop through the blocks then compare the gameobject instance.

```
for (int i = 0; i < blocks.Length; i++)
{
  if (hit.collider.gameObject == blocks[i].gameObj)
  {
    Debug.Log("Block hit is " + blocks[i].gameObj);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I know the type of object it is hitting. They are all Block types. I am trying to identify which Block Object reference got hit.

Comment: @brainydexter - Seems like most people don't bother reading the actual question.

Comment: Modified the answer. I read the question and the code. His comment actually explains what he really wanted properly.

Comment: Is there a better way of identifying the correct Block other than looping all the blocks ? I have quite a few blocks and everytime I click ( which I foresee to be a lot), this will be quite an expensive operation!

Comment: c# built in array loop is very fast. Using List and any other method will be slower. I suggest you go with the array method. It is the fastest way to do this as  far as I know. With the `break`, it will stop looping once it finds the block.

Comment: If this solved your problem you can just accept it as the answer. Thanks

Comment: @Programmer  man I gave him the same answer dont know what he means by object reference .

Comment: @LumbusterTick. Reference is when you get the instance of the object so that you can modify it later on. If he gets the reference of that GameObject, he can modify it later on. Comparing Object by reference is faster then comparing it by name or even by tag because name and tag comparison are both doing string work which is slow. Examples of reference:  `GameObject newGameObj = oldGameOBject`.  Now oldGameObject reference is gotten and save in `newGameObj` reference. You will understand this very well if you learn C++ pointers and pass by reference function.

Comment: Speaking about my answer, that's the solution. he has to **loop** through the gameobjects to find the one clicked since this is array and as far as I know, there is no other faster way to do this. He just doesn't want to accept it as the answer and is asking for better way to do this even when there is non. Happy Codings!

Comment: I know what that means I asked as in Heck What the hell he means kinda way  and I also told him about getinstanceid using a loop , some people just want to watch the world burn .http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/getinstanceid-what-is-it-really-for.293849/

Comment: Lol... he can use getinstanceid too as long as there is a way to convert instanceid to gameobject or `Block` instance. I just researched and  I didn't see a way to do that in runtime....although you can in Editor mode.

Comment: @Programmer what are you saying ? gameObject.getinstanceid == gameobject.getinstanceID what is there to convert , this runs in runtime I use it to compare objects in a list when deleting

Comment: @Programmer I ended up instantiating all the blocks at `Awake()` and store them in a dictionary indexed by getInstanceId(). When I select an object, I index into the dictionary like this `hit.transform.gameObject.GetInstanceID ()`. Saves me from looping :) I have multiple clicks happening and lot of objects. If I end up looping for all of them, I was thinking it would slow down! O(n) vs O(1)

Comment: @brainydexter, I mentioned something about using List in my comment and I said using List is slower than using array. That also applies to Dictionary. Raw array is about 6.5 times faster than Dictionary. If you are using Dictionary to make it easy for you then go for it. If you are using Dictionary because you think is it very fast, you are wrong. I know my answer has been accepted but i still want to correct you because you think Dictionary is faster than array. I've done the test before and take a look here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-dictionary-test

Comment: @Programmer Agreed. However, between array vs dictionary, it depends the operation you are performing. If you are directly indexing into the array. That is going to be fastest. However, if you are looping in array to find element(and your element happens to be at the end of array (length: n)), it will take O(n) time. Compared to dictionary, it will take some constant time to compute the hashKey, and then lookup based on that hashKey which is constant time. In this usage, dictionary will be faster.

Comment: I could have used array of Blocks also, but then the instanceId returned is negative and then I wont be able to index into the array with a negative index. Hence, I used dictionary. Thoughts ?

Comment: You can use Blocks but that will likely  require the use of getComponent and you know that is slow. It is good if you have many ideas on how to do this. The best advice I have for you is to write each idea into different functions, then use C# timer to time each method. Then you will find out which one is the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

In your if block use the hit parameter to detect which object was hit , because it has the information what the ray collided with , example hit.collider.tag == "myBlock"

Comment: Please look at the Block class I am defining. I need a reference to which Block Object got hit.

Comment: Oh ok I understand so  you can use GetInstanceID of the hit colllider gameobject and run a for loop of your array to check which one was hit.

Answer (score 0):

I like your question. And I think I got the key of what make the above 2 answers be not you want.

Usually, unity developers want to make this kind of block, they will **create a cube and add script as element to it** to make a prefab.

However,  What you do to define a block is more programmer, **creating a C# class with a primitive cube.**

I think one way is to check the block's position.x and z with the position of each block in the array .because the blocks are dropping, then just y is changing, to check x and z is a solution.

Hope help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the unity way of doing this would be ? Also, blocks will be moving along x axis also (not Z), so I don't think that would work.

Comment: Select the block, check it which index in the list,  is this what you mean in the question?